# Java ArrayList - can't read back properties of objects

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I want to be able to make an array list of objects, and then be able to edit and read back some simple properties of each object.  In this case, a `String (colour)` and `integer (X)`.  I can't seem to make the simple code below work.  Note that I am aware people sometimes use the <> notation with array lists, but I have read that it should be possible without, and at the moment I am very new to Java and wish to keep things as simple as possible.

At the moment I get an error on the line which is commented out (cannot find symbol X)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArrayList_of_Objects {

 public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

        for(int i =0;i<5;i++)
        {
            MyObj ob1 = new MyObj();
            ob1.X = i + 5;
            al.add(ob1);
            //System.out.println("X: "+al.get(i).X);
        }
        for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
        {System.out.println("X: "+al.get(j).X);}

        al.get(3).X=4;
        al.get(3).colour="orange";
        System.out.println(al.get(3).X);
        System.out.println(al.get(3).colour);
  } 

}

class MyObj
{
    int X;
    String colour;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to use [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) to say what kind of object will be in your list:

```
ArrayList<MyObj> al = new ArrayList<MyObj>();
```

Otherwise the compiler doesn't know that `al.get(3)` is meant to return a `MyObj` rather than just anything. With this code, it will not only fix the `get` calls - it will stop you from accidentally adding objects of inappropriate types to the list.

Also, it's usually preferred to declare variables as an appropriate interface type, such as:

```
List<MyObj> al = new ArrayList<MyObj>();
```

(There are times where you really need it to be the concrete type, but generally prefer programming to interfaces.)

Generics is a *massive* topic, but the tutorial linked at the start of this answer should get you going. The [Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html) is a great resource for finding out more.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer.  Does this mean then that it is not possible to achieve my goal without the generics <>?  I guess I will have to read up on them, but if there is a simpler way in the mean time, then I would be interested to know !

Comment: @user2094585: Well you could cast, or use an array instead - but it would be best to learn generics. They're a core part of modern Java.

Comment: OK Jon, I will have a look at both.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
    ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
```

to

```
    ArrayList<MyObj> al = new ArrayList<MyObj>();
```

What you have right now is an array list of `Object` rather than an array list of `MyObj`, and `Object` has no knowledge of `MyObj.X`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ArrayList<MyObj> al = new ArrayList<MyObj>();` instead

Comment: use List<MyObj> al = new ArrayList<MyObj>(); instead